# C++ linking issue: multiple definition

Tags: g++, linker-errors, multiple-definition-error

Unfortunately I cannot post all of the source code here.  I can describe the structure though.  All header files have #ifndef/#define/#endif guards.  The structure is as follows:

- node.h - included by tree.h
- tree.h - included by tree.cpp and main.cpp
- tree.cpp
- main.cpp

In node.h in the global namespace, I declare the following free standing function:

```
bool char_sort_func(Path first, Path second)
{
  return (first->label() < second->label()); 
}
```

(Note: as shown bellow, a Path is just a shared_ptr)  When I try to build, I get a multiple definition error saying that the function is present in both tree.o and main.o:

```
> make
g++ -c -g -Wall main.cpp -I /usr/include
g++ -c -g -Wall tree.cpp  -I /usr/include
g++ -Wall -o tool tree.o main.o -L /usr/lib -l boost_program_options
main.o: In function `char_sort_func(boost::shared_ptr<Edge>, boost::shared_ptr<Edge>)':
node.h:70: multiple definition of `char_sort_func(boost::shared_ptr<Edge>, boost::shared_ptr<Edge>)'
tree.o:node.h:70: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I tried searching all of the source files to see if that was true, however, I don't see it in any wrong places:

```
> grep char_sort_func *
Binary file main.o matches   
node.h:bool char_sort_func(Path first, Path second) 
node.h:    std::sort(edges_.begin(), edges_.end(), char_sort_func);
Binary file trie.o matches
```

Sure enough though, it is in the binary files.  How can I restructure my code to prevent this linking issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will happen if you declare normal functions in a `.h` file, because they will be generated in every file that `#include`s it.  Perhaps you meant to declare it `inline` or `static`?